# remove read-only ISOFS file system created by startup disk creator

Tags: 20.04, usb, filesystem, read-only, startup-disk-creator

I created a bootable Ubuntu-20.04 USB disk using startup disk creator by Ubuntu. The boot is working fine and installed Ubuntu too. But, it has left my USB derive unusable. Whenever I try to format/reformat it or copy/paste into it or create/delete a partition in it, it gives error that it's a read-only file system, ISOFS. I've tried many solution over internet but none is working. Is there any way to remove read-only ISOFS file system??

Thanks

Comment: Create a new partition table on the media; ie. formatting it should achieve this (note: that's formatting the device & not a partition on the device).  USB *flash* media is a consumable item, and will fail at some stage during a write; your *media* may just need to be replaced.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue.